# installing GlusterFS 3.7.5 on AWS AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, rsyslog, glusterfs

I am trying to install Gluster 3.7.5 on Amazon Linux AMI but cannot get passed error

```
Error: Package: glusterfs-libs-3.7.5-1.el7.x86_64 (glusterfs-epel)
           Requires: rsyslog-mmjsonparse
Error: Package: glusterfs-3.7.5-1.el7.x86_64 (glusterfs-epel)
           Requires: systemd-units
```

I cannot find the rpm or needed libraries to get `rsyslog-mmjsonparse` installed.

Does anyone know how to get passed this?

Answer (score 0):

`rsyslog-mmjsonparse` is part of the base repository for RHEL-7 and CentOS-7. If you use Amazon Linux, verify that it is based on el7 too. If not, you should probably install the el6 version of the Gluster packages from http://download.gluster.org/pub/gluster/glusterfs/3.7/LATEST/EPEL.repo/epel-6/